# Splitting up a large storyboard into modules

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I have a fairly large UITabBar-based app with most of it's views defined in a storyboard.
Right now, I only have a single "Main" storyboard, but I would like to break it into modules.
It looks like many of the flows I can group into a module diverge from a single tab which has it's own navigation controller.

Is there a way for that navigation controller to control the views I load from another storyboard? Or will I need to define a new navigation controller as the root of the new storyboard?
Also, is there a way for the back button on a navigation controller on storyboard B to return to the last view controller seen on storyboard A?

Comment: Did you try creating a test project and running a little experiment?

Comment: I did it in my actual project, on a separate branch from my main work. When I split a section to a new storyboard, I lost the nav bar, and couldn't get it to display without creating a new navigation controller.